# How to create a nuget package with .cshtml file containing a helper method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I am trying to create a Nuget package for an MVC helper method which I have created recently.

The helper method is in .cshtml file inside App_Code folder of the MVC project structure.

I am trying to follow [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593605/All-you-need-to-create-a-Nuget-package-for-ASP-NET) to create a nuget package for this. 
I have performed following steps -

- Created a class library project
- Created app_code folder
- Copied helper method from the MVC project to a file insider app_code folder in the class library project.
- Added reference of System.Web.Mvc in the class library project
- Added reference of System.Web.Razor and System.Web.WebPages.Razor dlls

However, when it is showing me following error when I try to import System.Web.Mvc in the class library project
there are no build provider registered for the extension ".cshtml"

Any idea/ tutorial of how can we create a nuget package containing ".cshtml" file containing a helper method.
I don't want cshtml file to be added in the package, instead, i would want that to be accessible through DLL only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked this out myself.
Basically, I had to use RazorGenerator package, and had to set it as a custom tool in Razor file. And yes, it compiled the whole cshtml in a DLL.